Inherit override-equivalent as different methods
Several methods from interface, super class or new method are override equivalent. I need to make different realization for each. Example:

public interface A {
    int f();
}
public interface B {
    int f();
}
public class C implements A, B {
    // ???
}


C c = new C();
// return values doesn't matter
c.f(); // must print "C"
((A)c).f(); // must print "A"
((B)c).f(); // must print "B"

In C# it would be
// "print" prints first argument to the console
public class C : A, B {
    public int f() { print("C"); }
    public int A.f() { print("A"); }
    public int B.f() { print("B"); }
}

When created function int f(), all override equivalent methods were same.

have you tried default methods? The better question is: why would you need something like this in the first place?

^I just tried default methods because I wanted to suggest it too, but it wont work because the implementation in C would override the A and B default methods. Unless you created another method for A and B inside C which calls A.super.f() and B.super.f()

@BIBOOunit one of the main reasons it doesn't work, is because it really shouldn't. anyway, my guess is Andrew 'll be more served with some weird Factory pattern

In Java, you can't directly achieve this because Java doesn't support explicit interface implementation like C#. When a class implements multiple interfaces with the same method signature, the class must provide a single implementation for that method. Maybe you can use a workaround by creating wrapper classes for each interface and then delegating the method call to these wrapper classes.

I think Hagelslag as the right idea. Instead of implementing A and B, add methods that expose views of types A and B: public A asA() { ... } and public B asB() { ... }. If the interfaces have only one method you can use lambdas, e.g. public A asA() { return () -> print("A"); }. Otherwise you can create a private nested class (static or not) and return an instance of that.

As a continuation of my comment, I would like to include a code sample as well here. Again it is not directly possible in Java. But as a workaround, quote: "...use a workaround by creating wrapper classes for each interface and then delegating the method call to these wrapper classes."
Here is the code:
interface A {
    void f();
}

interface B {
    void f();
}

class WrapperA implements A {
    private final C c;

    public WrapperA(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("A");
        c.f();
    }
}

class WrapperB implements B {
    private final C c;

    public WrapperB(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("B");
        c.f();
    }
}

class C implements A, B {
    @Override
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }

    public static A asA(C c) {
        return new WrapperA(c);
    }

    public static B asB(C c) {
        return new WrapperB(c);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        c.f(); // prints "C"

        A a = C.asA(c);
        a.f(); // prints "A" and "C"

        B b = C.asB(c);
        b.f(); // prints "B" and "C"
    }
}


